# Twilio socket drops after a period of time

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I've noticed after some amount of time ~ 20 minutes after I initialize chat, the connection drops and throws this error.

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Can't connect to twilsock`

Is there any way to prevent this or reinitialize the chat when that happens?

Comment: this happens to me too on React Native, when the apps enters background for some minutes.